# Line chart in Google Data Studio with x-values spaced according to their value

Tags: charts, looker-studio

In Google Data Studio I'm struggling with building a (simple?) line chart. I'm trying to get a plot with just two lines:

- A horizontal line from (0,0) to (0,22)
- A vertical lines from (20,-7) to (20.001,15)

Currently my data looks as follows:

[image: InputData]

Somehow I cannot change the x-axis to be continuous, so my chart ends up like this:
[image: Wrong graph]

My x-value (X) is numeric. Would it be possible to get the desired graph with two lines and with the x-axis spaced according to the x-value? My chart settings are as follows:

[image: Chart settings]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You don't really want a "line plot", but you seem to want a "connected scatterplot":

- https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/connectedscatter.html

That's not supported by the Data Studio native visualizations, but you could create your own "Data Studio community visualization" to support this:

- https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization